# Easy to understand and browse diff between two directories

Tags: git, diff

I have two directories that are different versions of the same code. There are a lot of changes (`diff -r` spits out a few megabytes), but most of these changes are repetitive (a version number change at the top of every file, for example). Right now I'm piping the output of diff into `grep -e -v 'PATTERN1|PATTERN2'` etc, but this produces something a lot less readable than a typical `git diff`.

**How can I diff 2 directories, eliding certain patterns, such that the output of the diff is easy to read and work with?**

Comment: You may have better luck using something like https://pypi.org/project/unidiff/ to parse the diff. That would give you the option of applying the regexes to complete hunks rather than just lines.

Comment: @jdowner: You might want to add that as an answer.